# Problem with client.channels.get();/client.channels.find();

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have been working on a discord bot and I want to send a message as soon as it gets online in a set announcement channel. I think I know how to make it work but I keep getting the same problem. I've read several articles but they don't solve the problem I have `client.channels.get is not a function`.
I don't just want to change it to a channel Id as I want it to be possible to be used on other servers than mine. I am a newbie in discord API and coding in general. That is why I don't use too advanced coding as I want to learn what it does instead of copying something I don't understand.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get any properties from the `client` object, it needs to be loaded from within an event. Say for example inside the `ready` event, i.e. when the bot is fully loaded, you can then do `client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name == "name_of_channel")`, etc. To listen to an event, you do `client.on("event_name_here", (parameters) => {})`.

To view a list of events, take a look at: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client

If this didn't help, please post your code so we can properly determine the issue.

Comment: Wrong. Even if the client wasn't yet logged in, `channels` would've been an empty collection, which can't lead into a "get is not a function" error. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61365444/15145899) comment is correct.

Comment: @itzJOH_ I am not sure how my answer is wrong? I stated to use `client.channels.cache.find` exactly the way the comment to referred to did. I am also aware that the client must be logged in before the collections are populated, hence why I mentioned the need to run it inside an event listener such as the `ready` event after the bot is logged in. I fail to see how I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Since discord.js v12 you now need to use [`.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=cache) to access `channels` collection.

Use `client.channels.cache.get()` or `client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'Test')` instead.

Comment: Oh, I might just looked at older posts then. thanks.